# Retrieve the particular customer ID from a Database while selecting a customer name from Spinner with the help of Webservices?

Tags: android, api, web-services, spinner, android-spinner

How to retrieve the particular customer ID while I am selecting a customer name from the spinner?

My code is,

```
public void parseJsonResponse_Edit_Lv_Receipt_Details(String result) {
    Log.i(TAG, result);

    // you can use this array to find the school ID based on name
    ArrayList<SpinnerClass_ITEMS> customers = new ArrayList<SpinnerClass_ITEMS>();
    // you can use this array to populate your spinner
    ArrayList<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> customerIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json.getString("customer"));
        Log.i(Edit_Lv_Receipt_Details.class.getName(),
                "Number of entries " + jArray.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("Check json object in View CUstomersList:" +jObject);

            String json_id=jObject.getString("id");
            System.out.println("Customer ID is:"+json_id);

            SpinnerClass_ITEMS customer= new SpinnerClass_ITEMS();

            customer.setId(jObject.getString("id"));
            System.out.println("Check ID:"+customer);

            customer.setName(jObject.getString("name"));
            System.out.println("Check Name:"+customer);
            customers.add(customer);
```

Getting Customer Names ie. Retrieving the customer names from a Database and displaying it inside spinner:

```
            customerNames.add(jObject.optString("name"));
            System.out.println("Print customerNames:"+customerNames);

**//Getting Customer IDS ie. Retrieving the customer IDS from a Database and storing it in arraylist//**

            customerIDs.add(jObject.optString("id"));
            System.out.println("Print customerIDS:"+customerIDs);

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sp_lv_Receiptedit_lv_receipt_Fees_Name.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, customerNames));



   **/*Selecting spinner position and corresponding values and displaying with the help of toasts*/**

    sp_lv_Receiptedit_lv_receipt_Fees_Name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String  itemValue    = (String) sp_lv_Receiptedit_lv_receipt_Fees_Name.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int itemPosition     = position;
            Hold = sp_lv_Receiptedit_lv_receipt_Fees_Name.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1 ;
            Toast.makeText(Edit_Lv_Receipt_Details.this,"Position :"+itemPosition+" ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

In the above code, I am populating the datas inside spinner with the help of webservices.

In Logcat,

Here, printing customer Names :
Print Customer Names:[Pooja, Rakesh, saranya, Devikaa, meenakshi, Meena, Rengarajan, Rengarajan, Meena, Meena, Meena, akila, customer, Meena, Meena, Meena, Meena, Laila, Susila, Manu, Rengarajan, Ravi, Meena, Prabhu, Prabha, Zealoit, ZealoitVijay, Leo, prabha]

Here, printing customer IDs by storing in an arraylist with the help of webservice URL :

System.out: Print Customer IDS:[1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37]

But what I need is, need to retrieve the particular customer ID when I select the customer name from a spinner?

How to get the customer ID (Check Json responses) for a particular selected customer name while I am selecting the spinner value?

**JSON RESPONSE is:**

```
{
"customer": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Pooja"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Rakesh"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "saranya"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "Devikaa"
}, {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "meenakshi"
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Rengarajan"
}, {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "Rengarajan"
}, {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "16",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "18",
    "name": "akila"
}, {
    "id": "20",
    "name": "customer"
}, {
    "id": "21",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "22",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "23",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "25",
    "name": "Laila"
}, {
    "id": "26",
    "name": "Susila"
}, {
    "id": "27",
    "name": "Manu"
}, {
    "id": "28",
    "name": "Rengarajan"
}, {
    "id": "29",
    "name": "Ravi"
}, {
    "id": "30",
    "name": "Meena"
}, {
    "id": "31",
    "name": "Prabhu"
}, {
    "id": "32",
    "name": "Prabha"
}, {
    "id": "33",
    "name": "Zealoit"
}, {
    "id": "34",
    "name": "ZealoitVijay"
}, {
    "id": "35",
    "name": "Leo"
}, {
    "id": "37",
    "name": "prabha"
}]}
```

Comment: please add your json response to populate spinner.

Comment: i'd suggest you to narrow down your question and be specific about what you want to do

Comment: @Tej - I need to retrieve the customer IDs while I am clicking customer names from a spinner?
System.out: Print SchoolIDS:[1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37]

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan-blueGem you have not add you json response. add your json response to get idea to fetch customer id.

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan-blueGem   map your customer id with customer name . after selecting name from spinner . search your name in the list and get its respective id by position

Comment: @Tej That is school ID not custome id.

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan-blueGem please clarify schoolid is customer id or not.

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan-blueGem please tell me what is the print this line  System.out.println("Check json object in View CUstomersList:" +jObject);

Comment: @Guruji as OP mentioned in the question its seems like school Id is customer ID :) . she should change the tag in her print log and that's why i asked her to be specific about problem

Comment: School id is customer ID..

Comment: Please check my json responses. I have edited the post!

Comment: @Tej How do I map customer ID with customer name? Yes, I am able to get the position and corresponding values from a spinner while I am selecting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 sp_lv_Receiptedit_lv_receipt_Fees_Name.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                String  itemValue    = (String) sp_lv_Receiptedit_lv_receipt_Fees_Name.getItemAtPosition(position);

                String customerId = customerIDs.get(position);

                Log.i("Customer Details","Customer Details "+ itemValue  + customerId);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Customer Name "+ itemValue + " Customer ID " + customerId ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**Selected Name ID**

[image]

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan-blueGem please check my ans and tell me if you have any problem.

Comment: @MeenaRengarajan-blueGem Thanks, Happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 3):

Here i am adding dummy values to ArrayList and checking it in spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

```
customerNames.add("Anitha");
customerNames.add("Devi");
customerNames.add("Suja");

customerIDs.add("3");
customerIDs.add("5");
customerIDs.add("8");

sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, customerNames));

sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       Log.e("customer_id", customerIDs.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

This log returns corresponding id

Answer (score 0):

Here you are getting corresponding customer ID in one list and also you have the position of each spinner value.
if Customer list is

```
List<String> cus_list={ "Anitha", "Devi" , "Suja","Puppy","Kishri"};
```

So if we select Devi postion is 1

and Customer id list is

```
List<String> cus_id_list={ "12", "3" , "6","43","21"};
```

The size of the list will be same.So here we have position of spinner, It will be equal to the postions of list's.

So , we can get from cus_is_list like

```
String id = cus_id_list.get[1]
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest the issue in this ?